# What are the numerical values for clockid_t macros?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I would like to pass in clockid_t macros as a compile-time argument (`gcc -D CLOCK=CLOCK_REALTIME file.c` ), to define the macro CLOCK in my code. How do I find out their respective integer values so I could do that?

The 4 clockid_t's I need are the ones listed on the man page: https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime

The system is Linux.

Comment: You could write a little program to learn them: `printf("CLOCK_REALTIME = %d\n", CLOCK_REALTIME);`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Steve I should have thought of that - though it is true as Remy notes that the values of the macros can change from platform to platform.

Comment: You do realize that `-D` doesn't have to take an integer, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in `<time.h>` to get the actual values.

However, note that the system-defined clock IDs can differ in value from platform to platform. For instance, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is `1` on Linux, but is `4` on FreeBSD.

So, you are better off defining your own macro values, and then map them to the appropriate clock IDs in your code using the constants in `<time.h>`, which are based on which platform(s) you compile for.

```cpp
#include <time.h>

clockid_t GetDefinedClock()
{
    #if CLOCK == 1
    return CLOCK_REALTIME;
    #elif CLOCK == 2
    return CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
    #elif CLOCK == 3
    return CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID;
    #elif CLOCK == 4
    return CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID;
    #else
    #error "NO CLOCK DEFINED!"
    return 0;
    #endif
}

clockid_t clock = GetDefinedClock();
// use clock as needed...
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do anything! `-DCLOCK=CLOCK_REALTIME`, or whatever, on the command line will Just Work.

This is because the body of a macro is macro-expanded *after the macro is expanded*, not when the macro is defined. So, as long as `time.h` has been included before `CLOCK` is *used*, `CLOCK` will be expanded and then `CLOCK_REALTIME` will be expanded too.